# How long process executeQuery() method?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, executequery

I have new simple SELECT query in Oracle.

If i run on SQL tool it takes 1~3 second.

But on java jdbc using executeQuery() method, it takes 30~40 second

Why its takes so long? what I consider to solve this problem?

please help for newbie

i just upload my java source
but cannot query upload
it is too long fo upload

```
    pstmt   =   con.prepareStatement(Query);
    pstmt.setString(1,  model.B_BasicDate);
    pstmt.setString(2,  GL_bfMonth);
    pstmt.setString(3,  GL_bfDay);
    **rs = new DmdResultSet(pstmt.executeQuery());  // it takes 35 seconds**
    int  colCount       =   rs.getColumnCount();
    Vector  innV        =   null;
    while(rs.next()) {
        innV        =   new Vector();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= colCount; i++) {
            innV.addElement(rs.getString(i)) ;
        }
        outV.addElement(innV);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code and sql query you want to execute. :)

Comment: @kitonlee provide code with query

Comment: @kitonlee edit your answer and post your code there, the comment section is not the right place to do that

Comment: The SQL you want to execute would be helpful as well .. Or are all statements slow?

Comment: all sql query are slow on java

Comment: thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

There are some screws like `setFetchSize` and autocommit/transactional mode.
However *first* try running the application with more memory (java -Xmx=...),
as you are doing bulk work.

As on efficiency:

- Declaration as close to their first use; inside a loop does not change
  its storage.
- Vector is a very old class. Use (Array)List. It is faster.
- `SELECT many fields` is inefficient, especially for CLOB and such.

So:

```
// The normal I use, but there are faster ones
connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
connection.setReadOnly(true);

List<List<String>> outV = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    List<String> innV = new ArrayList<>(colCount);
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= colCount; i++) {
        innV.add(rs.getString(i)) ;
    }
    outV.add(innV);
}
```

By the way method, variable and field names should start with a small letter and be camelCase, without underscores. This is a rather strict convention by the java family.

Comment: thank you for your help i'll try this thank you so much